# how to increase camera resolution when using IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

Tags: android, camera

I run my android application with camera functionality implemented in an 
android-powered phone, but the camera image I got always has small 
resolution. It seems by default, the android camera resolution is 
small (e.g. 640*480), how to increase the resolution??

I use the following code to implement the camera part:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"); 
File photo=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "123.jpg"); 
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo)); 
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

any suggestions on this???

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tried it myself, but you could try to add the `EXTRA_VIDEO_OUTPUT` extra in the intent.

Just add:

`i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_OUTPUT, 1);`

See [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION%5FIMAGE%5FCAPTURE) for further information.